# Future Date in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I need to display Future Date in a webpage. like 24 days after today only month and day. can anyone please help me. Like

This item will deliver in :(+24 days).
e.g.
This item will deliver in: Dec 6

I like to Display Month and Day only, is it possible. Thank you.
PS. I am using WordPress and WPBakery Page Builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this into your functions.php and output with shortocde

```
[delivery_date]
```

```
function delivery_date_shortcode() {
    // Get today date
    $today = new DateTime();
    // Add 24 days to today date
    $delivery_date = $today->modify('+24 days');
    $formatted_date = $delivery_date->format('M j');

    // Return the formatted date
    return "This item will deliver in: {$formatted_date}";
}

// Register the shortcode
add_shortcode('delivery_date', 'delivery_date_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to get it:

```
const displayDate = (inDays: number) => {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + inDays);
    
    return currentDate.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: 'short', day: '2-digit' });
}
```

Just get the future date (according to `inDays` param) and then use the function to "extract" the date information for your needs

Comment: Sorry I am not expert in web development. a am using WordPress and WPBakery Page Builder, can you please guide how to insert this?

Comment: @IsuruPathum I have never used these 2 tools so I cannot help here except for giving the question solution you asked for

Comment: Thanks for the help, and sorry for i didn't mention those before exactly.